# How do you define custom hash for strings in ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

I would like to hash strings in ruby by the characters in each string without order, for example I would want all anagrams to have the same hash value.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why not just sort before hashing?

Comment: Can you post an example of an input and desired output?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, what's the point of hashing if you sort?

Comment: @CarySwoveland because if you sort them first, anagrams become the same word

Comment: Yes, I know, but my point is that if you sort both words there is no need to obtain hash codes (just see if they are then equal).  I expect that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
require 'digest'

string = "MySuperSampleString"
sorted = string.chars.sort.join

p sorted
# => => "MSSSaeegilmnpprrtuy"

Digest::MD5.hexdigest(sorted)
# => "ef86bea3ade82ae7bf0409952bc83fd7"
```

- `chars` "splits" the string to letters
- `sort` sorts the letters array
- `join` joins the array of letters into one string

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the use-case is actually for anagrams, you might also want to use `.downcase` and `.gsub(/\s+/, "")` so that Torchwood == Doctor Who. ie:

```
string.downcase.gsub(/\s+/,"").chars.sort.join
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible using group_by. Just one line of code. :)

EXAMPLE:

```
words =  ['demo', 'none', 'tied', 'evil', 'dome', 'mode', 'live',
          'fowl', 'veil', 'wolf', 'diet', 'vile', 'edit', 'tide',
          'flow', 'neon']

groups = words.group_by { |word| word.split('').sort }
```

Returns:

{["d", "e", "m", "o"]=>["demo", "dome", "mode"], ["e", "n", "n", "o"]=>["none", "neon"], ["d", "e", "i", "t"]=>["tied", "diet", "edit", "tide"], ["e", "i", "l", "v"]=>["evil", "live", "veil", "vile"], ["f", "l", "o", "w"]=>["fowl", "wolf", "flow"]}

```
groups.each { |x, y| p y }
```

Returns:

["demo", "dome", "mode"]

["none", "neon"]

["tied", "diet", "edit", "tide"]

["evil", "live", "veil", "vile"]

["fowl", "wolf", "flow"]

Comment: Grouping by the product of the codepoints will match some strings that aren't anagrams, especially as you mix strings of different sizes.

Comment: Yes, very true. Please do not use this in real life stuff!!

Comment: In fact, if you just add the codepoints together, this program won't work. Hence why I had to multiply them  instead by using inject(:*)

Comment: Removed the codepoints example. I was scared someone might use it in practice. Thanks Andrew for pointing that out!